# ValueError: Mixed precision training with AMP or APEX (`--fp16` or `--bf16`) and half precision evaluation (`--fp16) can only be used on CUDA devices

Tags: deep-learning, transformer, gpu, finetuning, cuda

i’m fine tuning the wav2vec-xlsr model. i’ve created a virtual env for that and i’ve installed cuda 11.0 and tensorflow-gpu==2.5.0 but it gives the following error : ValueError: Mixed precision training with AMP or APEX (--fp16 or --bf16) and half precision evaluation (--fp16_full_eval or --bf16_full_eval) can only be used on CUDA devices.
i want to fine tune the model on GPU ANY HELP ?[image]